# Convert an integer (read with xlrd) back into a date format (write using openpyxl)

Tags: python, xlrd, openpyxl

I'm using xlrd to read some dates in a file, an writing them in a new workbook using openpyxl.

If the date is 25-jun-14, it writes 41815

I just want to know how to turn 41815 back into 25-jun-14 again, or 25/06/14 however all the material I've read today seems extremely overcomplicated.

Comment: Can you show us code you use to write to xlsx? Maybe you can do converting before writing.

Comment: first `originReport = xlrd.open_workbook('report1').sheet_by_index(0)` then `destReport = openpyxl.load_workbook('report2').get_sheet_by_index(0)` and finally I copy the info from one report to the other with `destReport.cell(row=1,column=1).value = originReport.cell_value(0,0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With openpyxl you could modify the file in place.

Nevertheless the conversion is pretty easy: Excel treats are numbers (with 1900-01-01 as the epoch) that are formatted as dates so you simply need to set the format of the cell.

```
originReport = xlrd.open_workbook('report1').sheet_by_index(0)
destReport = openpyxl.load_workbook('report2')[0]
c = destReport.cell(row=1,column=1)
c.value = originReport.cell_value(0,0)
c.number_format = "d-mmm-yy" # Excel's formatting
# check the conversion
print(c.value)
2014-06-25 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose value of `originReport.cell_value(0,0)` is `'25-jun-14'`.

```
from datetime import datetime
import re

a = '25-jun-14'
b = re.sub('-14', '-2014', a)

c = datetime.strptime(b, "%d-%b-%Y")

# write 25/06/2014
destReport.cell(row=1,column=1).value = c.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
```

I think you should write 2014 instead of 14. Otherwise, how can you tell which stands for year.